# Get ArgumentNullException when new gRPC channel on UWP release build

Tags: c#, uwp, grpc

I am trying to develop UWP with gRPC. I got channel `ArgumentNullException` on release build, but debug build is fine and gRPC also works fine. It seems to related to UWP limitation (loopback). I also use `checknetisolation` command to add exception for my package. But it's still fail. Is there any advice?

Updated more information, I already enabled debug trace on release build but callstack is still empty:

1. If Optimize code of build is checked, `ChannelCredentials.Insecure` is null.
2. If Optimize code is unchecked, `new Channel()` will get `ArgumentNullException`.

Anyway, `ArgumentNullException` happens on `new Channel()`.

#### Code:

```
var cert = ChannelCredentials.Insecure;
var channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:55168", cert);
```

#### Error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.'
```

#### StackTrace

```
System.ArgumentNullException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Value cannot be null.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

#### Output

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in 
System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Value cannot be null.
```

#### Package version:

```
Google.Protobuf version: 3.15.8
Grpc version: 2.37.0
```

Comment: Just to be clear: does `ChannelCredentials.Insecure` evaluate as `null`? or is something happening further in?

Comment: hmmm; looks like that comes from a static initializer, with no `#if` for different builds etc, so I'm *guessing* the linker has stripped it somehow? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/csharp/Grpc.Core.Api/ChannelCredentials.cs#L33

Comment: A stack trace here would be helpful...

Comment: Sorry for unclear information, updated more information

Comment: UWP seems not support for loopback

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found UWP seems not support loopback on release build, so I got null when create loopback socket channel. BTW, Microsoft allow create loopback on debug build for debug purpose.